# difference between two syntax new( int[ size ] ) and new int[ size ]

Tags: c++

**this text runs without any warnings or errors**

```cpp
int* iPtr;
unsigned int size;
cin >> size;
iPtr = new int[size];
```

**this one return warning but works fine why!!**

> warning: non-constant array new length must be specified without parentheses around the type-id [-Wvla]
>        iPtr = new (int[ size ]) ;

```cpp
int* iPtr;
unsigned int size;
cin >> size;
iPtr = new(int[size]);
```

Comment: That's just the rules of `new`

Answer (score 0):

This particular warning is issued because variable length arrays are not permitted in C++. The parentheses cause the compiler to see `int[size]` as a variable length array.

That is what the `-Wvla` corresponds to in the warning.

If you specify a constant value instead of user-specified value for `size`, you can use parentheses.

```
int main() {
    unsigned int* iPtr;
    constexpr unsigned int size = 10;
    iPtr = new (unsigned int[size]);
}
```

See **[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PeL3Ad)**

Comment: Can, but still shouldn't.  `new` is not a function.